# function returning constructor and calling directly

Tags: javascript, constructor, inline, short

I'm currently coding in Javascript and calling a function that returns a constructor, I would like to immediately create the object like this. but I does not work. because I want this code in one line instead of having to make another var to initiate it.
Thanks in advance.

```
this.vendor = new Lib.vendorAPI.retreiveVendor(this.vendorConst)(this);
```

this way it works, but its not inline.

```
var currentVendor = new Lib.vendorAPI.retreiveVendor(this.vendorConst)(this);
this.vendor = new currentVendor(this);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: *"because I want this code in one line "* - sacrificing readability for wants? Hmm...

Comment: in this case its cleaner to write it inline, otherwise you will the variable currentVendor and this.vendor.
but I'm with you when you say that the readability is harder. that is true.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer myself: 
adding brackets around the function will tell the browser that it first needs to execute the function and then create the instance from the returned constructor.
like this:

```
this.vendor = new (Lib.vendorAPI.retreiveVendor(this.vendorConst))(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var currentVendor = new new Lib.vendorAPI.retreiveVendor(this.vendorConst)(this);
```